# Reference a group of cell's formula rather than the value

Tags: microsoft-excel

With reference to [Reference cell's formula rather than the value in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/950220/reference-cells-formula-rather-than-the-value-in-excel), I wish to see if anyone can help me in the situation:

I got several spreedsheets 'Result1', 'Result2', ... 'Result50'.
The top few lines of the the spreedsheet contains various formulae with similar references, like:

| Cell | Formulae |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | `=sum(A10:A20)` |
| A2 | `=average(A10:A20)` |
| A3 | `=counta(A10:A20)` |

in all 50 spreadsheets. It would be hard to modify the formulae one by one. (e.g. sum -> sumif, counta -> countif) So I wonder if I can set a master spreadsheet 'Formula' (say) which save the three formulae above, and reference cells on those 'Result' spreadsheet to the cells in 'Formula'.

I knew normal reference would give values only. But I really want to see if there are smarter way to handle this. Thank you very much.

Comment: `FORMULA(cell)` - gives the formula in a cell as text, now how to use it...

Comment: Are you asking how to update the formulas in a handful of cells in a bunch of similar (identical?) spreadsheets so they all have the same new formulas in them? Sounds like a macro job if that is the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's what you meant, but check it out.

In this variant of the solution a defined `LAMBDA` function named `CLONE` with one argument (source address) retrieves a formula from a cell with a given address, executes the body of that formula, and places the result at the place of the call.
If the source formula refers to cells without a qualifier, then the formula in the destination worksheet will refer to the same cells in the current worksheet.

`LAMBDA` Function Definition (in Name Manager)

```
=LAMBDA(x, EVALUATE(FORMULATEXT(x)))
```

This formula uses the old XLM macro function `EVALUATE`, so the workbook must be saved in a macro-compatible format, e.g. .xlsm

For example, in the `Formula` worksheet in cell `A1` there is a formula:
`=SUM(A10:A20)`
In the `Result1` sheet you put the following entry:

```
=CLONE(Formula!A1)
```

This formula calculates the value of `SUM(A10:A20)`, but the arguments come from the worksheet `Result1`.
If you now change the formula in `Formula!A1` to `=AVERAGE(A10:A20)` the result in `Result1` will change accordingly to `AVERAGE(A10:A20)`.

Comment: Thanks! This is EXCATLY what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two tricks that can make this task easier for you.

**First:** create a named range, for example with the name `rangeForCalculate` and the formula `INDIRECT("A10:A20")` and in all your formulas use this name:

```
=SUM(rangeForCalculate)
=AVERAGE(rangeForCalculate)
=COUNTA(rangeForCalculate)
```

The trick is that since there is no sheet name specified in the string **"A10:A20"**, `INDIRECT()` will refer to the specified range in the same sheet where the name `rangeForCalculate` is used.
Now to change the range just change this string **"A10:A20"** in the named range.

**Second:** leave everything as it is. Just before editing formulas, click on the tabs of the desired sheets while holding down the Ctrl key to select the sheets you need, or click the first tab and Shift-click the last tab. Now edit the formula and the changed formula will appear in all selected sheets at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. But what I mean is that I have to change the formulae instead of the range.

Comment: The second trick will help with this. However, the first trick can also work if you create three named ranges with the necessary formulas and use an entry like `=Range_Name_1`. You edit a formula in one place, and it is immediately recalculated in all cells where this named range is mentioned